# Environment specific Nuget feeds: how to deal with local solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

We set up multiple nuget feeds for our different environments,
so there is no chance packages that are still in development are accidently used in production code when auto merging packages.config files.
Package versions are synced between the feeds, so we can merge our packages.config without problems.
In Teamcity we can enable the correct feeds for each environment,
but sometimes the Production solutions need to be opened locally.
In this case we want Visual Studio to only restore packages from our production feed and not from Development.
Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling your DEV feed, and then adding/enabling your PROD feed (locally) is likely going to be the best way to handle this.

There is no better means of pulling packages from a specific feed for development/debugging purposes, unless you can consider your 'DEV' packages to be 'prerelease' packages (which nuget tooling has explicit support for, but which I do not suggest you bother due to end-user confusion in larger teams.)

Once done, you can disable the PROD feed and re-enable your DEV feed.

HTH

Comment: as an aside, the way some of my clients handle this is to only produce PROD packages (and, thus, DEV necessarily is only ever using a production quality package.) This does, however, require pre-planning and forethought when changing enums, schemas, etc and thus does not work for poorly planned/executed codebases (e.g. where developers expect to change an enum, entity definition and dependent code all in one pass.)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution for this.
Only producing PROD packages isn't an option for us, as we use Nuget packages to for parts of our UI in some cases.
To set up a test environment the Nuget test packages need to be made.